# Calculate values in strings

Tags: vb.net

I need to calculate labels values and I want the result to be formatted with 2 decimals digits.
The code I'm using is:

```
Dim culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("us-US")
Dim diff = CDec(CStr((Decimal.Parse(Label13.Text, culture) * Decimal.Parse(Label16.Text, culture)))) - Decimal.Parse(Label15.Text, culture)
  
If diff > 0 Then
Label20.ForeColor = Color.Green
Label20.Text = CStr(diff) '((CDbl(Label13.Text) * CDbl(Label16.Text)) - CDbl(Label15.Text)).ToString("n2")
Else
Label20.ForeColor = Color.Red
Label20.Text = CStr(diff) '((CDbl(Label13.Text) * CDbl(Label16.Text) - CDbl(Label15.Text))).ToString("n2")
End If
```

The input is:

> label13.text= 0,600

> label15.text=11,157

> label16.text= 18,110

> label20.text should be= -0,29
> instead, the output im getting is

> label20.text= - 4462,800

Where it comes from?

It s quite weird cause with this input it's working

> label13.text= 1000

> label15.text=107,4

> label16.text= 0.10296

> label20.text= -4.44

Thanks

Edit1:

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Net
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class Form1

    'DICHIARO I WEBCLIENT
    Private ReadOnly wcBTT As New WebClient()
    Private ReadOnly wcUNI As New WebClient()
    Private ReadOnly wcVET As New WebClient()
    Private ReadOnly wcCAKE As New WebClient()
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Label4.Text = My.Settings.BTTQ
        Label5.Text = My.Settings.BTTP
        Label6.Text = My.Settings.BTTINV
        Label7.Text = My.Settings.UNIQ
        Label8.Text = My.Settings.UNIP
        Label9.Text = My.Settings.UNIINV
        Label10.Text = My.Settings.VETQ
        Label11.Text = My.Settings.VETP
        Label12.Text = My.Settings.VETINV
        Label13.Text = My.Settings.CAKEQ
        Label14.Text = My.Settings.CAKEP
        Label15.Text = My.Settings.CAKEINV

    End Sub

    Private Async Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        'FERMO IL TIMER ALTRIMENTI OPERAZIONI I/O SIMULTANEE
        Timer1.Stop()

        Dim downloadTasks As New List(Of Task(Of String))

        ' SCARICO IL CONTENUTO DELLE API E LO DICHIARO "DIM BTC AS TASK(OF STRING)
        Dim btt = wcBTT.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=BTTBUSD")
        Dim uni = wcUNI.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=UNIBUSD")
        Dim vet = wcVET.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=VETBUSD")
        Dim cake = wcCAKE.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://api.binance.com/api/v1/ticker/24hr?symbol=CAKEBUSD")

        downloadTasks.Add(btt)
        downloadTasks.Add(uni)
        downloadTasks.Add(vet)
        downloadTasks.Add(cake)


        Await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks)

        'DESERIALIZZO LE API NORMALI
        Dim settings = New JsonSerializerSettings With {.Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture}
        Dim d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(btt.Result, settings)
        Dim d1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(uni.Result, settings)
        Dim d2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(vet.Result, settings)
        Dim d3 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))(cake.Result, settings)

        Dim PREZZOBTT As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(CStr(d("lastPrice")), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Dim PREZZOUNI As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(CStr(d1("lastPrice")), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Dim PREZZOVET As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(CStr(d2("lastPrice")), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        Dim PREZZOCAKE As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(CStr(d3("lastPrice")), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        'CONNETTO LE API NORMALI ALLE LABEL 


        Label1.Text = PREZZOBTT.ToString("n7")
        Label2.Text = PREZZOUNI.ToString("n3")
        Label3.Text = PREZZOVET.ToString("n5")
        Label16.Text = PREZZOCAKE.ToString("n3")

        'GAIN/LOSS
        'BTT
        Dim diffbtt = (PREZZOBTT * Decimal.Parse(Label4.Text) - Decimal.Parse(Label6.Text)).ToString("n2")
        If CInt(diffbtt) > 0 Then
            Label17.ForeColor = Color.Green
            Label17.Text = CStr(diffbtt)
        Else
            Label17.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Label17.Text = CStr(diffbtt) '
        End If


        ''UNI
        Dim diffuni = (Decimal.Parse(Label7.Text) * PREZZOUNI - Decimal.Parse(Label9.Text)).ToString("n2")
        If CInt(diffuni) > 0 Then
            Label18.ForeColor = Color.Green
            Label18.Text = CStr(diffuni)
        Else
            Label18.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Label18.Text = CStr(diffuni) '
        End If


        ''VET
        Dim diffvet = (PREZZOVET * Decimal.Parse(Label10.Text) - Decimal.Parse(Label12.Text)).ToString("n2")
        If CInt(diffvet) > 0 Then
            Label19.ForeColor = Color.Green
            Label19.Text = CStr(diffvet)
        Else
            Label19.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Label19.Text = CStr(diffvet) '
        End If


        ''CAKE
        Dim diffcake = (Decimal.Parse(Label13.Text) * PREZZOCAKE - Decimal.Parse(Label15.Text)).ToString("n2")
        If CInt(diffcake) > 0 Then

            Label20.ForeColor = Color.Green
            Label20.Text = CStr(diffcake)
        Else
            Label20.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Label20.Text = CStr(diffcake)
        End If

        Timer1.Start()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235798/discussion-on-question-by-mattia-calculate-values-in-strings).

Answer (score 0):

I would drop Decimal type, use Double, and use the string Format command for ensuring 2 digit precision in the results of the delta (`diff`).  The parsing can take a string argument, so you don't need to convert to CDbl() first -- besides, how can you convert to double if you are trying to determine if what's being tested is double?  The return from Format is a string result, so it doesn't need CStr(), .ToString, etc.

```
Dim lab3, lab5, lab6, diff As Double
Dim parseresult As Object

If Double.TryParse(Label3.Text, parseresult) = True Then 
    lab3 = CDbl(Label3.Text)
End If
If Double.TryParse(Label5.Text, parseresult) = True Then 
    lab5 = CDbl(Label5.Text)
End If
If Double.TryParse(Label6.Text, parseresult) = True Then 
    lab6 = CDbl(Label6.Text)
End If

diff = lab3 * lab6 - lab5

If diff > 0 Then
   Label20.ForeColor = Color.Green
   Label20.Text = Format(diff, "0.00"))
Else
   Label20.ForeColor = Color.Red
   Label20.Text = Format(diff, "0.00")
End If
```

If you need to kill the currency type, i.e., if "$" is in the label strings, then replace it with

```
lab3str = Label3.Text.Replace("$","")
```

and then parse lab3str.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, as you can see I need a solution ((a*b)-c) while your example is showing a-b.. Am I wrong?

Comment: Modified answer to be in line with a * b - c. BTW, you don't need parens around (a  * b), since compiler math always performs * and / first, followed by + and -.  So in a * b + c * d, the result is (a * b) + (c * d).

Comment: I'm sorry It still doesn't work, it might be a problem of formatting.. 
Input: lab3=0,600 lab5=11,157 lab6=18,033  Output is : 10608.4

Comment: Probably the Nationale (region settings). If commas are decimals in the currency you are using, then replace the commas with a decimal like `Dim lab3str As String = Label3.Text.Replace(",",".")`, then parse the lab3str before calculations.  Sounds like you want 0.6 * 11.157 - 18.033?  You know that's going to be negative?

Comment: Write out the worked answer like ans = a * b - c , and XXX.XXX = XXX.XXX * XXX.XXX - XXX.XXX is where you fill in the numbers.  Certainly, according to math calculations, you just need to convert what's in the label text values to a real number with decimal precision.  VB.NET will then do the math independent of currency and symbols like $ and commas (",").   Fortunately, in math, 1.5 in the US equals 1.5 in the EU.

Comment: hi,this is the [link](https://pastebin.com/nbEj2fCM) with the code you wrote. It doesn't work, it doesn't calculate the numbers, it gives me a 9 digit number...
What I want to do is 0.600 * 18.110 - 11.157= -0.29
The problem is the culture, I also added the replace , with . but the values are not changing at all!

Comment: Place a debug break point on line 3 (just mouse click in far left gray column at line 3), then run.   At run-time, compiler will stop at line 3, then hover the mouse pointer over `lab3str` to the left of "=" sign on line 2.   What do you see for a number?

Comment: What happens if you add this to your code somewhere, then run, what appear in the message box?  `Dim a,b,c As Double`, `a = 0.600`, `b = 18.11`, `c = 11.157`, and then `diff=a*b-c`, followed by `MsgBox(diff)`

Comment: i get -0,291. It might be the way i'm populating some labels through input box.. I should filter something in the input box

Comment: about the break point:

lab13str= 0.600
lab15str = nothing
lab16str= nothing

Comment: The answer is correct and you are done.  (all the math you do inside VB.NET will have commas as the decimal point when viewing parameter values during run-time, and you will never have a period "." as a decimal).  Thus, don't replace commas with periods in the input label text values.  Just do as you are doing and input "0,690" for label3, etc.  You can add break points and hover over all the intermediate values at run time.   Just tweak until you get what you need.  You can also show all the label values using MsgBox(lab3), or MsgBox(lab3str), etc.

Comment: if i put a break point on "diff = lab13 * lab16 - lab15" it gives me:
lab13=600
lab16=17337
lab15=111600
which are all wrong.. the real values are 0.600, 17.337 and 11.1600

Why can't I get those values?

Comment: But if you still need to show a decimal in the output, probably use e.g. `Label20.Text = diff.ToString.Replace(",",".")`, or `Dim diffstr As String = Cstr(diff)`, then `diffstr = diffstr.Replace(",",".")`, and finally `Label20.Text =diffstr`.   However, I don't what happens in your locale for large numbers like one million here in the US is 1,000,000.00, so is it 1.000.000,00 in your locale?

Comment: From the web: "So, if your web designer in Spain sends you an invoice for 10.000,45 euros, or your project manager in Denmark sends you an invoice for 10 000,45, it means ten thousand euros and forty-five cents. A vendor in the US would write the same amount as 10,000.45"

Comment: do you mean something like this [link](https://pastebin.com/rMz8Q9tu) ?
it gives me 10258200 instead of -0,something

Comment: I really don't care about the format tbh, i usually don't use any comma or . for integers, but for decimals I use both commas and .  but as i can see the software doesn't like this. I need to put a filter format inside the input box. Look, this is the entire code [link](https://controlc.com/5b173941) of the other code I'm doing with @Jimi , can you see the way I'm using the input box? It might be the format input box is filling labels.

Comment: Sounds like the parser is stripping out the comma and not giving you 0,690 (0.690 in US).  Try this trick: `Dim l3, l5, l6, odiff as Object`, `l3=Label3.Text`, `l5=Label5.Text`, `l6=Label6.Text`, `odiff = l3 * l6 - l5`, `Msgbox(odiff)`

Comment: Error BC30038 Option Strict On prohibits operands of type Object for operator '*'. on "odiff = l3 * l6 - l5"